# Clip heat map so it does not extend past boundaries of another layer

Tags: qgis, clip

I have the following heat map that was created from clusters of vector points. I have a second layer underneath this heat map that shows the U.S. How do we prevent the heat map from extending past the boundaries of the U.S.?

[image]

Comment: Try making a duplicate of the USA states layer, put it at the top of the layers list, and use the 'inverted polygons' renderer...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you created this heatmap in the screenshot with the layer styling options of your point layer.
In order to clip your heatmap, you need to create it as a raster. Go to: "Processing Toolbox" -> search for "Heatmap", customize the options at your will and save the heatmap as .tif

To cut your newly created raster to the extend of your underlying layer, go to: "Raster" -> "Extraction" -> "clip raster by mask layer".
The rest should be self explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You could also edit the color ramp (under the heatmap settings under symbology) - edit "color 1" so that it is transparent or very low opacity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Duplicate the layer representing the US
2. Bring it to the top in the layer panel
3. Set its rendering style to Inverted Polygons

Now it will visually cut everything that is ouside the shape of the US. Set the color to white or whatever you like.

[image]